# Import a files like PDF MP3 DOC XLS into a MS SQL Server Datatable field

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

does anybody know how to save and retrieve files in MS SQL-Server 2000?  I guess the image data type could be used as a container.

I want to import/export the following file types: DOC, XLS, PDF, BMP, TIFF, etc.

Due to resource issues we are using MS-Access 2007 as the front end, so I am looking for VBA code.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

I advise you (really!) not to try (ever!) to save files as data in a database. You will quickly face critical space problems.

Please think about creating folders for file storage. These will be used to save/archive your files. Folders paths can be stored in one of your tables (`Tbl_Folder`, for example). You can then store your file names in a table (such as `Tbl_File`, where you'll have a '`filename`' field). You will be able to open it with the `Access.followHyperlink` method and to manage it (copy/delete/move) with the [File Scripting Object](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3709941/File-Management-with-Scripting-Object.htm) (FSO).

Comment: While I agree with your main point about avoiding storing files in the database, there's one exception: if you are using replication. In that case, storing the files in the database is the easiest way to keep multiple locations synchronized with the same data in the files.

Comment: But the cost of storing files in the database (in terms of disk space and volume of exchange) is so huge that we developped a "home-made" solution by combining data replication and files & folders replication.

Comment: I think there are probably several techniques for synchronizing file systems that are probably a lot less problematic than db replication.  I vote for not storing files in the db.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using GetChunk and AppendChunk.

From [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/9acef36c-0f2d-4fa1-b71f-172a0ac89c4b/) you might find [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;194975) helpful!

One thing to watch out for:

> When using certain providers, most
>   notably ODBC to SQL Server and other
>   databases, you may have to take
>   special care in retrieving BLOB data,
>   such as placing BLOB columns at the
>   end of the field list and referencing
>   all non-BLOB fields prior to access
>   BLOB columns.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with streams. This code should help you with the first steps:

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "select * from YourTable", Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

Set mstream = New ADODB.Stream
mstream.Type = adTypeBinary
mstream.Open
mstream.LoadFromFile "c:\myfile.pdf"
rs.Fields("blobfield").Value = mstream.Read
rs.Update
```

There is nothing dangerous about storing files in a database. We have a SQL Server database of about 20 GB which contains about 40.000 documents, images, etc. Never had a problem with it in over 3 years.